# How do I load all the data from a webpage with Qliksense?

Tags: web, web-scraping, load, qliksense

So what I want do do is, **get the all the data from this webpage** *http://abreview.ru/stat/aeb/* on QlikSense Desktop.

**My Attempt**
I tried to do this in data load editor through web file as a connection, but it only loaded a part of the data (part that can be seen without chaining the data filters when the webpage is first loaded)

**So, how do I can the full amount of data be loaded**, what are some good ways of doing this.

I could copy the data into excel file and then load it through excel but it is a lot of algorithmic work and I want to find an efficient solution, that is if there is one.

Comment: I'm not familar with qlicksense, but a litte bit with qlikview. I think the easiest way is to tell your web-application to send out all the data when calling the url. Otherwise you have to implement some client side logic while loading the data. (Iterate over pages...)

Answer (score 1):

Great question, I've done this as a step by step process as I've never done this before either.

To connect to the website, you need to open the data load editor.

On the right hand side you need to "create new connection"

[image]

You then enter the URL and name it
[image]

Once this is created, the connection will appear on the right, click the select data icon.
[image]

You then need to pick the table you want to load, I'm assuming you want the fifth one.
[image]

Then click insert script and load data.
[image]

You can then get on with creating your apps.
[image]